# change default device for run app in device manager android studio bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio

I change device emulator in bumblebee android studio every time I started. how to set default emulator?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the android studio will save the last virtual device that you used, but you can change it manually.

In the project directory, set your default device in `.idea/deploymentTargetDropDown.xml`

```xml
<targetSelectedWithDropDown>
  <Target>
    <type value="QUICK_BOOT_TARGET" />
    <deviceKey>
      <Key>
        <type value="VIRTUAL_DEVICE_PATH" />
        <!--edit this line-->
        <value value="change-to-default-device.avd" />
      </Key>
    </deviceKey>
  </Target>
</targetSelectedWithDropDown>
```